# I removed the battery icon from the menu bar. How do I add it back?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My menu bar looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the battery icon is missing because I accidentally removed it by CMD+Click+Dragging it off of the menu bar. Also, the customize toolbar button is not clickable.

Comment: Actually, you dragged it off the menu bar. The toolbar is the area at the top of a Finder window, just below the title. That's why customizing the toolbar won't put it back.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simple way, goto "System preferences" -> "Energy Saver", and check "Show Battery status in menu bar"

Answer (score 2):

You can find the battery.menu among others in the

/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras

double click on it to get it back in the menu bar.

Or more simple way, just enable it in Energy saver as Show Battery status in menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to system preferences and click on energy saver. There, you check the unchecked "Show battery status in menu bar". Your battery should appear.

Comment: Hi Hazel and welcome to Ask Different.  Consider adding a screen capture to your answer to help the user identify what you are referencing.  We are looking for answers that are more than one line long and have good explanations.

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163821).